# Chromecast get volume

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

Just double checking: there is no way to get a current volume on a "casted" device using chromecast iOS SDK? Even though there is a setter method in `GCKDeviceManager`?

What should be the value of the volume slider when user connects to chromecast? Using device's volume might be confusing, when a device has the maximum volume, but TV is muted for instance... Anyone has the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same issue, here is the answer: there is no "getVolume" method, but you can get the volume in `mediaControlChannelDidUpdateStatus:` method

```
- (void)mediaControlChannelDidUpdateStatus:(GCKMediaControlChannel *)mediaControlChannel 
{
    float volume = mediaControlChannel.mediaStatus.volume;
}
```

Comment: Now you can get the device's volume level through the GCKDeviceManager's `deviceVolume` property.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GCKUIDeviceVolumeController` class. It has property `volumeSlider: UISlider?`. Just set your slider to this property and Google Cast SDK will handle changes from both sides.

In your class:

```
weak var volumeSlider: UISlider!
var volumeController: GCKUIDeviceVolumeController

func syncronizeVolumeSlider() {
    self.volumeController.volumeSlider = self.volumeSlider
}
```